# PHP comparing a regex and a string

Tags: php, regex

```
preg_match('`/`', '/hello/how are you/now/4/details')
```

The above and below returns true. Problem is I need only the below comparison to return true.

```
preg_match('`/hello/how are you/now/\d+/details`', '/hello/how are you/now/4/details')
```

I have a list of regex patterns and I need to see if the input/needle matches exactly one of the regex as illustrated above

Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is looking for a match for the pattern in the string. `/` is there so it returns true.
Use `^` at the beginning of the pattern to match the beginning of the string. Use `$` at the end to indicate end of string.

Comment: You mean something like this? preg_match('`^/$`', '/')

Comment: Use `.+` or `.*`. `.` covers for any character, but only once. Repetition operators tell the regex engine to use the `.` more than once. `*` is 0 or more times, + is 1 or more.

Answer (score 0):

First one will returns true because it finds `/` in the given string. If you want specific string match, as @JNF said use `^` and `$` for beginning and ending of the string.
To test your regex use https://www.debuggex.com it really helps you.